# I can't see the Field List items in GridControl Designer

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

I have two tables. You can see it on the attachment.

[My tables]

[image]

I want to show 'Personal Table' on GridControl but i want to see 'YerAdi' column instead of 'Yer_ID'. I mean i need something like Value Member and Display Member on gridcontrol column.

I am using dataset connection.

I am selecting both of those tables to create a dataset for the gridcontrol. After that i am clicking run designer/columns tab but i can't see anything on the field list.

Comment: Can you past the code when you affect datasource to GridControl

Answer (score 0):

you need to display both the column ID and Name but after assigning data to grid hide the column which one you don't want using below code.

```
grid.Columns("ColumnName").Visible = False
```

Comment: Yes you are right but still i can't use both tables on gridview.

Comment: then you need to perform join query between both the table